# How to send state data to API which expects json gunzip file as payload (ex: sample.json.gz) in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have constructed a json data,

```
sample =[]; if (this.state.data) { console.log(this.state.data); this.state.data.map((Number) => { console.log(Number); Sample.push({ Number: Number, Attributes: { 'subAttribut': { Name: 'Name_ok', GroupName: 'GroupName_ok', }, }, }); }); }
```

I need to store this json data into a json file say sample.json,
then I need to gunzip it say sample.json.gz,
then I need to pass this file as a payload to an API in reactjs.

Or is there any other way to send this sample data as sample.json.gz file as payload to API

Comment: Where does the data originate from?  Is the JSON entirely constructed in a browser client, and theres some remote API which expects the data in gzip format?

Comment: data in constructed based on state data like the following 
    let sample =[];
    if (this.state.data) {
      console.log(this.state.data);
      this.state.data.map((Number) => {
        console.log(Number);
             Sample.push({
          Number: Number,
          Attributes: {
            'subAttribut': {
              Name: 'Name_ok',
              GroupName: 'GroupName_ok',
            },
          },
        });
      });
    }


I need to store the sample data in json file , then gunzip it and send it to api

Comment: yes the remote api expects the data in gzip format.

Comment: What does _"write data to JSON file"_ mean? A browser can't write files on the disk. Why do you need to write the data into a file?

Comment: The API excepts the data in gzip file format

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Writing a file to the filesystem and sending a zipped file are completely unrelated.

Comment: I just want to know how can I send my sample data as json.gz file as payload?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Currently it's unclear.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-gzip seems to be a useful place to start, regardless of whether the OP wishes to compress an actual file containing JSON or just a JavaScript string containing JSON.

Comment: May be my question is not clear but the requirement is I need to send the sample data as a gz file to api.

Comment: So How can I store the data of sample to a json.gz file before sending it as payload to api?

Comment: The goal of Stack Overflow is to collect questions and answers to help future users. The goal is not to help one individual with their requirements. An unclear question isn't useful for future users.

Comment: I agree with you, you can correct the same in the comments with the solution if you have to requirement I explained, So it might help someone with same kind of confusion.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the given answer doesn't answer your question? AFAIK it's not possible to store a file in a real filesystem, gunzip it there, read it and send it. You could do all the steps in the browser. There is no JSON in the code snippet.

Comment: I will use this to get json object 
var samplejson =JSON.stringify(sample);

Comment: Is this problem solved? There is an answer, but you didn't accept it.

Comment: const compressedReadableStream = inputReadableStream.pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'));

What is inputReadableStream here?

Comment: Your JSON string as a stream

Comment: Because the problem is not yet solved.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the answer doesn't answer your question? Maybe you could also comment the answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to any kind of backend serving this javascript client, the best solution would be to proxy your JSON through your own backend, gzip it there, and send it to the final destination.

If you must do it in the browser, you could try the [Compression Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Compression_Streams_API) - But browser compatibility seems quite narrow still.

Edit: @ant Also pointed out this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-gzip

Comment: @jabaa The compression streams API lets you gzip JSON in browser memory.  How is this not an answer?

Comment: I think theres a misunderstanding on the original question because it is admittedly not very well worded.  I believe OP has some JSON in javascript memory, and wants to gzip it before sending to a remote web API, which can be done without involving an actual file.  But perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: The first thing i did was ask a comment on the question to clarify it.